# Showing unique records on time intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
Date               Name              Subject
----               ----              -------
01.03.17 10:03:00  Joseph            English
01.03.17 11:04:00  Joseph            English
01.03.17 13:05:00  Joseph            Math
01.03.17 14:03:00  Carl              French
02.03.17 09:02:00  Joseph            French
02.03.17 10:10:00  Carl              French
03.03.17 09:03:00  Joseph            Biology
04.03.17 16:03:00  Carl              Biology
05.03.17 12:03:00  Carl              English
06.03.17 13:03:00  Joseph            English
06.03.17 09:02:00  Joseph            English
06.03.17 10:06:00  Joseph            French
07.03.17 09:03:00  Joseph            Biology
```

I would like to Write a Query where I would:

- Select the month (for example, March, or from 01.03.17 to 31.03.17)
- Select a specific time interval (for example, 24 hours)
- show all the unique occurrences within all time intervals, as long as there was more than one occurrence per time interval. So if Joseph has English twice within 24 hours, this wouldn't show, but if he has English and French, then it would show the results.

The results would be like this:

```
Date               Name              Subject
----               ----              -------
01.03.17 10:03:00  Joseph            English
01.03.17 13:05:00  Joseph            Math
02.03.17 09:02:00  Joseph            French

01.03.17 11:04:00  Joseph            English
01.03.17 13:05:00  Joseph            Math
02.03.17 09:02:00  Joseph            French

01.03.17 13:05:00  Joseph            Math
02.03.17 09:02:00  Joseph            French


04.03.17 16:03:00  Carl              Biology
05.03.17 12:03:00  Carl              English


06.03.17 09:02:00  Joseph            English
06.03.17 10:06:00  Joseph            French

06.03.17 10:06:00  Joseph            French
06.03.17 13:03:00  Joseph            English
07.03.17 09:03:00  Joseph            Biology

06.03.17 10:06:00  Joseph            French
07.03.17 09:03:00  Joseph            Biology

06.03.17 13:03:00  Joseph            English
07.03.17 09:03:00  Joseph            Biology
```

Is there any way to do this without using loops to select the time intervals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This Query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1baa4/28

If it's ok then you can handle the Result formation logic in server side code.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it is possible to form the result right on the sql? Like grouping by interval, for example?